# foreach issue when using php MVC/ajax/json to delete multiple records

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am listing a table which shows records from the database and each row has a checkbox with an ID value associated with it.

```
<label class="m-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="<?php echo sanitize($failed->order_id); ?>">
 <span></span>
</label>
```

Once the user has selected the checkboxes of the records they want to delete, the submit button is pressed and that triggers an ajax request.

```
$( '.delete-failed' ).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $( '#delete-failed' ).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: url + '/TransactionsAjax/deleteFailedTransactions',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $( 'delete-failed' ).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if(!data.success) {
            $( '.alert-danger' ).append(data.message).fadeIn();

        } else {


            $( '.alert-success' ).append(data.message).fadeIn();
        }
    })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
        });
});
```

That then goes to the controller:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $response = array();
    $message = '';


    $orderId = $_POST['order_id'];

    $data = [

        'order_id' => $orderId
    ];

    if($this->TransactionsModel->deleteFailedTransactions($data)) {
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Failed transactions deleted';

    } else {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

Which is supposed to send the data to the model:

```
public function deleteFailedTransactions($data)
    {
        $this->db->beginTransaction();

        try {

            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_summary` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
            $this->db->bind(":order_id", $order_id);

            foreach($data as $item) {
                $order_id = $item['order_id'];
                $this->db->execute();
            }


            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_detail` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
            $this->db->bind(":order_id", $order_id);

            foreach($data as $item) {
                $order_id = $item['order_id'];
                $this->db->execute();
            }

            $this->db->commit();
            return true;
        }

        catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->db->rollBack();
            echo $e;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting in console is:

> undefined index: order_id

It is referring to this line in the model:

```
$order_id = $item['order_id'];
```

I am not sure at which point the problem is, is it in the data being sent via ajax, should the foreach loop be in the controller instead.. I am not sure.

Comment: Is $item an object or an array? Try accessing the property with object annotation. 
BTW I am not sure that binding the param works just by changing the reference without rebinding it.

Comment: $item isn't an object so it won't work to use `$order_id = $item->order_id` if that is what you mean. I have used bind outside of the foreach loop exactly like this in another scenario and it worked so I am not sure that it is my bind that is the issue here.

Comment: Seems like a lot of mishandling of data and variable names. For one, in your model `$order_id` doesn't exist, you only passed in the `$data` variable, you might be looking for `$data['order_id']`. For another, this `$data` variable seems to be just an array that contains one order_id. It makes no sense to `foreach` loop on `$data` when it is hardcoded to contain one key,value pair.

Comment: @MichaelConard, thanks. I must have been confusing myself there regarding the variable names. Good point about the $data variable. I may as well just pass the ID straight through. Would like to mark your answer as the correct one but can't.

Comment: @user8463989 I posted it with a code sample so you can mark your question completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the mishandling of data and variable names; that is, consider how you are wrapping and passing data. Are you intending to pass one order id from the checkboxes at a time in the ajax, or multiple? It's unclear, so I've modified the code to handle one order id. If it's multiple, you need to loop in the controller and properly create an array of order ids from the post, and then properly foreach loop over each order id in the model and bind and execute the query for each. Make sure you're looping over the object actually holding the list of ids.

For one issue, in your model `$order_id` doesn't exist, you only passed in the `$data` variable, you might be looking for `$data['order_id']`, or simply passing in `$order_id` without encompassing it in the `$data` array.

Similarly, this $data variable seems to be just an array that contains one order_id. It makes no sense to foreach loop on $data when it is hardcoded to contain one key,value pair.

I would try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  $response = array();
  $message = '';

  $orderId = $_POST['order_id'];

  if($this->TransactionsModel->deleteFailedTransactions($orderId)) {
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Failed transactions deleted';

  } else {

    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
  }

  echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

And then the model:

```
public function deleteFailedTransactions($order_id)
{
    $this->db->beginTransaction();

    try {

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_summary` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
        $this->db->bind(":order_id", $order_id);

        $this->db->execute();

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_detail` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
        $this->db->bind(":order_id", $order_id);

        $this->db->execute();

        $this->db->commit();
        return true;
    }

    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->db->rollBack();
        echo $e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Seeing your html have `order_id[]` indicates you may be trying to send multiple. Depending on how data is passing, you may need to explode/implode the list differently than I am. Consider this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  $response = array();
  $message = '';

  $orderIds = $_POST['order_id']; //explode maybe

  if($this->TransactionsModel->deleteFailedTransactions($orderIds)) {
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Failed transactions deleted';

  } else {

    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
  }

  echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

And then the model:

```
public function deleteFailedTransactions($order_id)
{
    $this->db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        foreach($order_id as $id) {
          $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_summary` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
          $this->db->bind(":order_id", $id);

          $this->db->execute();
        }

        foreach($order_id as $id) {
          $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_detail` WHERE `order_id` = :order_id");
          $this->db->bind(":order_id", $id);

          $this->db->execute();
        }

        $this->db->commit();
        return true;
    }

    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->db->rollBack();
        echo $e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you might consider optimizing the foreach queries into one each, like this:

```
  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `order_summary` WHERE `order_id` IN (:order_id)");
  $this->db->bind(":order_id", implode(",",$order_id); //whatever gives you comma separated string
  $this->db->execute();
```

Note that I'm not running this code, so consider it guidance/PHP oriented pseudocode for you to figure it out yourself. Feel free to ask clarifying questions via DM.

Comment: Thanks Michael, turns out that just running a foreach loop in the model and changing it from $item to $data['order_id'] was all that was needed, so there is no need to mess about with explode/implode i.e.: `$this->db->query("DELETE FROM order_summary WHERE order_id = :order_id");
   $this->db->bind(":order_id", $order_id);
   
   foreach($data['order_id'] as $order_id) {
       $this->db->execute();
   }` 
But I am still going to remove $data and just pass in the id directly like you did in your example.